# Execute function after chain of observable subscriptions completes (Angular 2)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, promise, observable

I need to execute a function that works on the data resulting from a chain of observable subscriptions but only after it finishes creating my object.

Here's my chain:

```
 getFilters() {
        this.filterSvc.getCamps()
            .subscribe(
                c => {
                    this.filters = c;
                    for (let camp of this.filters) {
                        this.filterSvc.getBuildings(camp.id)
                            .subscribe(
                                b => {
                                    camp.buildings = b;
                                    for (let building of camp.buildings) {
                                        this.filterSvc.getFloors(building.id)
                                            .subscribe(f => {
                                                building.floors = f
                                            });
                                    };
                                });
                    }
                });
           // ONLY DO THIS AFTER THE OBJECT IS HYDRATED
           this.globals.setCampFilters(this.filters);
    }
```

As you can see, I need to create a subscription from each item returned from getCamps, and another from each of those results, etc... Then after all is said in done, I want to execute

```
setCampFilters(this.filters);
```

How can I wait until all my camps have buildings and all those buildings have floors before I go populate my filters?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `flatMap` operator along with `Object.forJoin`. Here is a sample:

```
getFilters() {
  this.filterSvc.getCamps()
        .flatMap(c => {
          this.filters = c;
          // Observables for all camps
          return Observable.forkJoin(this.filters.map(camp => {
            // Links camp with the result of getBuildings
            return Observable.forkJoin([
              Observable.of(camp),
              this.filterSvc.getBuildings(camp.id)
            ]);
          })
        })
        .map(results => {
          // Map results and link buildings with camps
          return results.map(result => {
            let camp = result[0];
            let buildings = result[1];
            camp.buildings = buildings;
            return camp;
          });
        })
        .subscribe(camps => {
          // ...
        ]);
```

Note that you can chain `flatMap` operators.

This article could interest you:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/04/18/interacting-efficiently-with-a-restful-service-with-angular2-and-rxjs-part-3/

Comment: It looks like you're on to something here but when implemented execution never reaches much of the inner code. Even after getting flustered and setting breakpoints pretty much everywhere most of it doesn't get hit and I don't get any errors, and ultimately my filters are never populated. With due respect, I have to wonder whether you're just seeding clickthroughs for your blog post or you actually thought through the issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.getFilters = function() {
  this.filterSvc.getCamps()
  .do((c: any) => this.filters = c)
  .flatMap((c: any) => Observable.from(c))   // convert from Observable<Array<Camp>> to Observable<Camp>
  .flatMap((camp: any) => this.filterSvc.getBuildings(camp.id).do(b => camp.buildings = b))
  .flatMap(b => Observable.from(b))
  .flatMap((building: any) => this.filterSvc.getFloors(building.id).do(f => building.floors = f))
  .subscribe(null, null, () => this.globals.setCampFilters(this.filters));
}
```

A series of flatMap turn the Observable from Observable<Array<Camp>> to Observable<Array<Floor>>, and you just need to call `this.globals.setCampFilters` on the onComplete event of it.

EDIT: I updated the code to stop Typescript compiler from complaining about incompatible types. I add `: any` where I think TS compiler would complain,  you're free to add `:any` before every `=>`

Comment: Your answer seems promising but I get a slew of errors resembling "Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'" and "property 'buildings' does not exist on type '{}'" and I can't hack a good way to tell TS that c is of type "MenuCamp" and that buildings is of type "MenuBuilding" etc...

Comment: if you're using TS you can replace `c => `, `camp =>` .... by `(c: any) => `, `(camp: any) => `.  You can try to replace `any` by its corresponding type later after the code is successfully compiled if you want (but I don't think it's neccessary)

Comment: And next time please consider adding `#typescript` tag. It's hard to tell from your code if you're using TS or ES6/7